# LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(...) occasionally throwing an InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using a java 1.8 `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue`, and when I call:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

it is very occasionally throwing an `InterruptedException`:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
```

which I think is happening because the following is returning true during the (indirect) call to `checkInterruptWhileWaiting() at AbstractQueuedSynchronizer:2079`

```
Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(...)
```

As a side note, `Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt` returns a `boolean`, but what does that `boolean` mean? I can't find any documentation on that Class/function.

I suspect that something is going on in another thread to cause this issue, but I'm not sure where to look right now.

Any help on understanding why the `InterruptedException` is being thrown would be very helpful.  I would really like to be able to reproduce it in a small test program, but it's in a big messy program right now so I'm trying to understand what things could cause this so that I can create a test program to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any other thread in your app that calls `Thread.interrupt()`? This is what's happening in `awaitInNanos()`:

```
if (Thread.interrupted())
            throw new InterruptedException();
```

If you control the threads, then you can override the `interrupt` method **just for testing**:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something longrunning
        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            // try-finally ensures to run both super.interrupt() and the deubg code 
            try {
                super.interrupt();
            } finally {
                // you can use any logging services that you already have
                System.out.println("--> Interrupted from thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.dumpStack();
            }
        }
    };
```

If you create the threads manually, you can override `interrupt()`. If you use executors, then you can provide a [`ThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html), that creates the threads with the right `interrupt()` method.

Here is a `main()` method that plays with this debug technique. Please note that you need to enter a line in `STDIN` or manually kill the process. Otherwise it's going to run forever (jvm restart).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("--> asdf");
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                br.readLine();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            // try-finally ensures to run both super.interrupt() and the deubg code 
            try {
                super.interrupt();
            } finally {
                // you can use any logging services that you already have
                System.out.println("--> Interrupted from thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.dumpStack();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    System.out.println("--> before interrupt");
    thread.interrupt();
    System.out.println("--> after interrupt");
}
```